# How to query an address that has sub-identity?

Tags: polkadot-js, api

Using `polkadot.js` api:

- How do I get from an address to the parent address/identity?
- Is there any way to traverse from an identity to the sub-identities?

Just calling the identity of the address returns `null`

```js
import { ApiPromise, WsProvider } from '@polkadot/api'
// import { hexToString } from '@polkadot/util'

(async () => {

  const provider = new WsProvider('wss://kusama-rpc.polkadot.io')
  const api = await ApiPromise.create({ provider: provider })

  var validator = { stash: "HyLisujX7Cr6D7xzb6qadFdedLt8hmArB6ZVGJ6xsCUHqmx" }; // METASPAN
  var identity = await api.query.identity.identityOf(validator.stash)
  console.log(identity.toString())
  // {"judgements":[[0,{"reasonable":null}]],"deposit":33333333000,"info":{"additional":[],"display":{"raw":"0x4d4554415350414e"},"legal":{"none":null},"web":{"none":null},"riot":{"none":null},"email":{"raw":"0x646572656b406d6574617370616e2e636f6d"},"pgpFingerprint":null,"image":{"none":null},"twitter":{"raw":"0x406d6574617370616e5f696f"}}}

  validator = { name: '☀️SHAWN☀️/08', stash: 'GvBUeTDynB9A7fFDPoBt3RGXSjZVeCetoXjYQ44cMNp5myY' }
  identity = await api.query.identity.identityOf(validator.stash)
  console.log(identity.toString())
  // empty

  console.debug('done')

  setTimeout(() => {
    process.exit(0)
  }, 5000)

})()
```

Answer (score 2):

If the identity is null, try querying `superOf`:

```js
  const parent = await api.query.identity.superOf(validator.stash)
  //console.log(parent.toString())
  var [parentStash, subId] = parent.toJSON()
  console.log(parentStash, '-raw-', hexToString(subId.raw))

  var parentIdentity = await api.query.identity.identityOf(parentStash)
  var idj = parentIdentity.toJSON()
  console.log('parent name:', hexToString(idj.info.display.raw))
```

produces:

```bash
{"judgements":[[0,{"reasonable":null}]],"deposit":33333333000,"info":{"additional":[],"display":{"raw":"0x4d4554415350414e"},"legal":{"none":null},"web":{"none":null},"riot":{"none":null},"email":{"raw":"0x646572656b406d6574617370616e2e636f6d"},"pgpFingerprint":null,"image":{"none":null},"twitter":{"raw":"0x406d6574617370616e5f696f"}}}

JHDDYty2cU6vjWyMF2kvNK9hRMAgH9THwqvQpUzqQQs7KJr -raw- 08
parent name: ☀️Shawn☀️
done
```